# How to find pattern ###_____### in a paragraph

Tags: search, design-patterns, wildcard

The project i'm working on is like this..
i have a String variable which stores something like a paragraph. from this i need to find all the occurances of the substring ###***_***### and extract the value between the "###" the value between ### can be anything..

i was thinking of using the split() function and comparing if each string stored has 2 ### patterns. but this seems a very inefficient way of coding, especially since the number of words can be huge.

can u please suggest any approach or function that i could use to find ###***_***### or directly the value enclosed by ###.. i don't know much abt regex, i have tried searching, but haven't really found anything useful yet..

thanks in advance..

Comment: Please update the tags and question to reflect languages and/or libraries you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The regex you need is:

```
(?<=\###).*(?=\###)
```

The PHP would look like (assuming you are after PHP code):

```
$subject = $yourstring;
$pattern = '/(?<=\###).*(?=\###)/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

$matches will contain all of your results in an array.

Answer (score 0):

For most any language these days you can find some sort of regular expression to do this.

```
 /###(.*)###/
```

But @MDM is correct - you need to add more context here.